# Strange behaviour with Xamarin Android product version number

Tags: xamarin, google-play, xamarin.android

We are trying to upload a Xamarin Android APK to Google Play and having some weird behaviours which I'm not sure how to fix.

Yesterday we manually an APK to Google Play as it was our first version that we were uploading. When we uploaded it, it seemed to get a version number that did not match the android manifest value of 1. The highlighted red area is the uploaded APK

[image: console-apk-list-first-upload]

We found an issue with the build so updated the code and we set the product number to a value of 2 in the android manifest file. This time we used Xamarin Studio to upload the APK vi the Archives list. You can see in the following image that the product number is set to 2

[image: xamarin package listing]

This resulted in two new entries listed in the console but again, strange version numbers. They are highlighted in the following image

[image: console listing after 2nd upload]

We have subsequently tried to upload the APK with product version number 2 but consistently get an error that we are trying to upload an APK with version number 1

[image: error after manual upload attempt]

Anyone understand what is going on and how to resolve this. The only thought I have is to update our version number to 131074 but not sure that will work

UPDATE

So haven't heard back from Xamarin or Google Play so i decided to attempt to do a new build but with a version number of 131074. I don't want to use a number so large but figured lets try it. However, I'm not able to build with it because there is a limit of 65535 on the product number.

Update 2:

As requested, here is a link to the AndroidManifest.xml. Unfortunately I do not have the original from when the versioncode was set to 1 anymore

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JerioCGxaKWHUwREtoaTNNRHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add your respective `versionCode` and `versionName`? Or just throw in your whole final `AndroidManifest.xml` from your `obj\Release\android` folder. From what I see here, it seems these are `Beta` packages, and it seems like it might have trouble with overriding the `versionCode` = 1 bit. Did this happen after you uploaded the same `versionCode` twice? `versionCode` can go up to 2100000000, so you should be able to at least *build* the app. You mentioned you followed two workflows. The first being manually creating the APK, the second via the Archive or did you use the GPS publish?

Comment: @JonDouglas I've added a link to a version of the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Initially I tried to upload the first APK (version code = 1) via the Archive Manager in Xamarin. This failed indicating I had to manually upload it. So I grabbed the signed APK and uploaded it manually. At this point i got the version code of 131073

Comment: So assuming you were to remove all of these Beta uploads, try again with the minimums, does it happen again? Just to be sure here, you are grabbing the .apk to manually upload to Google Play from Xamarin Studio vs. using the Publishing feature?

Comment: I'm unable to remove the Betas from Google Play. I wanted to try that but when I deactivate the 131073 version, I get 'It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 131073 to version 65537'

when I manually uploaded, I followed directions from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/manually-uploading-the-apk/

Comment: @JonDouglas any further thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: I would recommend asking Google Play Services support. They should be able to tell you what's going on. Then you can respond back to this question with those findings. Since the APKs are directly uploaded and kept by them, they should be able to comment on this.

Comment: @JonDouglas I already have and they pushed me to Xamarin. I've also reopened with them but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: I have not run into this, and I suspect it's something really small. However I haven't found any time to attempt an reproduce. Does this also happen with other apps? Have you tried a new app?

Comment: @JonDouglas I haven't tried with a new app yet. I wanted to validate the issue first or try another app with Xamarin support (ie yourself) over Skype to try to reproduce as I expect it will behave the same way. I reached out earlier to Xamarin Support again to try to organize a skype call if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were never able to solve this issue or understand why it happened. In the end I created a new project in Google Play, updated our package name to match the new project and did the process over. This time it worked. I tested it with about 4 different test projects just to be sure.

No idea why it happened originally